# how to present a pop-up message based on Observable property?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, typescript1.8

I have a pop-up message that I want to present when my observable is delivered, its a string observable.

this is my function that returns string observable:

```
public sendUpdate() {
 this._mtService.sendCurrentUpdate(this.myList).subscribe(
 res => this.messageToDisplay = res,
 error => this.messageToDisplay = error
 );
 }
```

this is my function that I present the pop up with the relevant message:

```
public showMessageDialog(message) {
    let config = new MdDialogConfig()
      .title('Message:')
      .textContent(message)
      .ok('Got it');

    this.dialog.open(MdDialogBasic, this.element, config);
  }
```

now, I want to know where and how should I call this message to present `messageToDisplay` when the observable is ready.

I t would be even better if you can tell me how I can show some loader while the observable is waiting to receive the string and then when its there present it...

I tried to do this:

```
public sendUpdate() {
     this._mtService.sendCurrentUpdate(this.myList).subscribe(
     res => this.messageToDisplay = res,
     error => this.messageToDisplay = error
     );
    this.showMessageDialog(this.messageToDisplay);
     }
```

but what happens here is that the first time i click on update i see an empty pop-up and if I click on it again I see the pop-up with the message, its obvious that it happens because the string didnt came back yet, but how do I get over it?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The functions you pass to `subscribe()` will be called later/asynchronously, hence you need to call `showMessageDialog()` later as well:

```
public sendUpdate() {
   this.showLoader();
   this._mtService.sendCurrentUpdate(this.myList).subscribe(
     res   => { this.stopLoader(); this.showMessageDialog(res); },
     error => { this.stopLoader(); this.showMessageDialog(error); }
   );
 }
```